# Vertical align navigation icon/button in header

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

^^^

**This doesn't solve my question my situation is different, because of the animated css navigation button. Can get it work like that: display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle; etc.**

I have a responsive header that shows a navigation button when in mobile size where you can show the rest of the menu items (disabled in example don't need it for my question).

Because i going to make the header responsive in height it is beter that the navigation button is always centered vertical. Now it is placed in the center with a top margin of 20px and because the button is 20px in height and the header is 60px it is centered, but that won't work if the header height changes responsively.

[--> **FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/t3uej5p9/)

[image]

**Code:**

```
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="col-nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></a>          
        <a href="#" class="home">Name</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical alignment of elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: I seen that, but can't get it to work in my situation. Do you know?

Comment: If you make a demo with your current CSS we might be able to offer suggestions.

Comment: this is my current css demo. Question is simple: i don't want to vertical centered like i done now, but i want to do it literally so it changes with the different header heights.

Comment: Nobody can't help me must be easy for the most of the coders here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can set it's parent's position to `relative` then you might be able to use

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

on the button

Comment: I didn't give much details here so I expect my answer to be stolen any time soon to someone willing to add a few more words and a flashy layout.

Comment: Thanks mate this did the trick: `.nav-btn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
  background-color: transparent;
} `

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t3uej5p9/3/)** Just changed margin value

**CSS:**

```
.nav-icon {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 7px;        
}
```

Comment: No that is not what i mean in my example the navigation icon/button already is centered vertically and that is done with a top margin of 20px, because nav-btn= 20px height and header= 60px, but i want to make the header height changes with different breakpoints i  need the icon to be centered literally and not like i done now.